# Confidence score random forest classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, residuals

I have a classification task for which I have a binary outcome -- however, I need to know the level of confidence in classifying each individual in with medical record (previously referred to as row).

The specific classification problem is how to ascertain if someone is pregnant based on medical records (there are approximately 200 available predictors: ICD codes, procedure codes, age, etc.).  I will be using a random forest classification tree algorithm.

Confidence could be a residual for the row, specificity, sensitivity/Recall, or f-score for the decision node for associated with a rows terminal node.

Note that I am using ensemble learning a neural network and logistic regression are already included.

Comment: I think this question could be made on-topic by removing the part about seeking a particular software package (which would generally be considered off-topic here) and focusing on the "how can I..." aspect.

Comment: I have voted to repoen, now that the focus is on the statistics instead of the software. While I believe my post to answer the question, if someone has a better answer, they should be able to post it. // Care to remove the [tag:r] and [tag:python] tags to further remove the focus on software? At no point does the question mention software, let alone a particular language.

Comment: You state *"I have a classification task..."*, a description of a task. But what is the statistics question?

Comment: What is the question? Which type of measure to use to express 'confidence'? How to compute such 'measure'? Etcetera

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus from the question: specificity, sensitivity/Recall, or f-score.

Comment: @EnglishmanBob and what is the question about it?

Answer (score 1):

Random forest inherently has this ability. Contrary to popular belief, a random forest does no classification. A random forest outputs values on a continuum. Those values can be compared to a threshold in order to make classifications (below threshold is negative, above is positive), but that is separate from the random forest (even if software typically bundles the two together).

For instance, the `randomForest::predict.randomForest` in `R` has an argument `type` that returns values on a continuum if you set `type = prob`. Importantly, these can be interpreted as probabilities, and those give you your confidence scores. Not only can you claim a classification, but you can claim the probability of that classification.

Random forests have this pesky attribute, however, that they tend to lack calibration. That is, when they predict an event to happen with probability $p$, the event does not happen in $p$ proportion of the times. The `sklearn` documentation has some [nice material](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-calibration-plot-calibration-curve-py) to introduce you to the idea behind calibrating probabilities. Two terms worth knowing for your research are "Platt scaling" and "isotonic regression".

Comment: Personally I prefer "ranger" because it is (much) faster.  For "Ranger" if you set "classification" to "TRUE", or if the target is a factor, then the output is a classification forest.  If "probability" is "TRUE" and target is a factor, then it grows a probability forest. 
 https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ranger/versions/0.15.1/topics/ranger